# Session gets lost after redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-4

When a user visits a `index` Im redirecting him to `show`. As you can see in `index` i'm setting a variable in setting

```
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, only: :show


  def show
     debugger
     render inline: "<h3>hello</h3>"
  end


  def index
     session[:user] = "hans"
     debugger
     redirect_to action: "show"
  end
```

When I use debugger in the action `show`:

```
   session 
     =>  #<ActionDispatch::Request::Session:0x7f9a8e0882e0 not yet loaded>
```

Then when I force to initialise the session with:

```
   session[:init] = true
```

Then there is a session but `session[:user] == nil` and the `session_id` is also different form the `session_id` I get in `index`.

**What do I wrong?**
**Why does it start a new session after the redirect?**

Thanks

Comment: That is strange, I don't observe such behavior. My `session` data is properly accessible in the target action. You also probably have some custom route for the `show` action as you don't have to pass an `id`?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect debugger is your problem in that you are interrupting the process of retrieving the session variable. If I do the following:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    session[:user] = "hans"
    redirect_to action: "show"
  end

  def show
    render inline: "USER:" + session[:user]
  end
end
```

I enter the url: **/posts/index**

And my output is: "User:Hans"